# Rails 4: Scoping has_many/belongs_to relationship on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a Rails newbie, working on my first project- it's an app to keep track of all my comics. A "Series" has_many "Comics" and "Comics" belong_to a "Series."

I'm working with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.3.

On my Series show page, I have a list of all the comics that belong to that series. I would like to be able to sort them be issue number or read/unread status.

So, I've written the following in my Comics model:

```
class Comic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :series

  validates :number, :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  scope :issue_sort, -> { joins(:series).order(number: :asc)}
  scope :read, -> { joins(:series).issue_sort.where("read == true") }
  scope :unread, -> { joins(:series).issue_sort.where("read == false") }

end
```

And my Series model looks like this:

```
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comics, dependent: :destroy

   validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }
end
```

This all works in the console, but the problem I'm having is when I try to implement this on my Series show page.

I'm pretty sure that I need to set up a custom route that takes a route parameter.

My show action in my Series controller looks like this:

```
def show
    @series = Series.find(params[:id])

    case params[:scope] 
  when 'issue_sort'
    @comics = @series.comics.issue_sort
  when 'read'
    @comics = @series.comics.read
  when 'unread'
    @comics = @series.comics.unread
  else
    @comics = @series.comics.issue_sort
  end
end
```

But I can't get my routes to work. I have tried the following three in my routes.rb file and all three give me an error.

**Attempt #1**

In my routes.rb file:

```
get '/series/filter/:scope' => "series#show", as: :filtered_comics
```

In my show template:

```
<%= link_to "Issue Number", filtered_comics_path(:issue_sort) %>
```

**Attempt #2**

In my routes.rb file:

```
get '/series/:series_id/filter/:scope' => "series#show", as: :filtered_comics
```

In my show template:

```
<%= link_to "Issue Number", filtered_comics_path([@series, :issue_sort]) %>
```

**Attempt #3**

In my routes.rb file:

```
get '/series/:series_id/comics/:id/filter/:scope' => "series#show", as: :filtered_comics
```

In my show template:

```
<%= link_to "Issue Number", filtered_comics_path([@series,@comics :issue_sort]) %>
```

I think that the second attempt might be the way to go, but I'm not totally sure. Set up that way, it gives me an error that reads:

*ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Series#show
Showing /Users/Jean/Documents/coding/my_projects/comics/comics/app/views/series/show.html.erb where line #6 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"series", :format=>nil, :id=>"1", :scope=>nil, :series_id=>[#, :issue_sort]} missing required keys: [:scope]*

Would it be better to write these scopes on the Comic model? Is it even possible to query the Comics from my Series show page?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but once try this: `<%= link_to "Issue Number", filtered_comics_path(@series, "issue_sort") %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about your routing and such, but I believe this would work.

```
<%= link_to "Issue Number", filtered_comics_path(@series, :scope => 'issue_sort') %>
```

Looking at your routes, you won't need an @comic variable passed in; you wouldn't be using it. You do need your @series variable though.

In your controller, you're switching based on params[:scope], so it's important that you give the key :scope, and whichever value you want to sort based on as the value.

Hope that helps.